# How to toggle image based on BooleanToVisibilityConverter?

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, datagrid

In a WPF DataGrid, I have a DataGridTemplateColumn:

```
<DataGridTemplateColumn>
  <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
    <DataTemplate>
      <Image Visibility="{Binding ShowImage, Mode=OneWay, Convert{StaticResource BooleanToVisibilityConverter}}" Source="{StaticResource Image1}" />
    </DataTemplate>
  </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
</DataGridTemplateColumn>
```

This column starts with no image. Then some processing occurs. If ShowImage is assigned true, an image is displayed. Else, nothing is displayed.

How do I toggle between two images based on the assignment to ShowImage?

Answer (score 0):

Just use another converter (maybe you can call it BoolToImageCoverter) that will assign one image if ShowImage is true and a different image if ShowImage is false.

Answer (score 0):

You could use another converter, or you could use `Style.Triggers`:

```
<Image Source="{StaticResource Image1}">
<Image.Style>
   <Style TargetType="{x:Type Image}">
      <Setter Property="Visibility" Value="Collapsed" />
      <Style.Triggers>
          <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding ShowImage}" Value="True">
             <Setter Property="Visibility" Value="Visible" />
          </DataTrigger>
       </Style.Triggers>
    </Style>
</Image.Style>
</Image>
```